# Task.Run does not execute all the httpwebrequest method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that sends a lot of httpwebrequests and reads data. So I decided to run each request on a different task. I ended up with having about 60 tasks to run. the problem is that the these requests does not get executed when I use task.run. In fact some of the requests gets sent to the server and responses back with data and a lot of them are just ignored. I was wondering if this is because of the CPU limitations and if so how would it be possible to handle such requests.

Example of the the method that requests data:

```
private static bool getResponseData(string url, string pageNumber)
        {
            url = url + "page=" + pageNumber;
            Uri myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            try
            {   
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader readStream = null;

                        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
                            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                        else
                            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                        string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                          //dealing with data by storing it in the data base
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        }
```

A method to loop throughout url pages

```
    private void startrequest(string url)
    {
        bool data2 = getResponseData(url, "0");
        int counter2 = 0;
        while (data2 && counter2 < 4)
        {
            counter2++;
            data2 = getResponseData(url, counter2.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Example of the use of the task.run in my application is as follows:

```
            Task task1 = Task.Run(() => startrequest("www.x1.com"));
            Task task2 = Task.Run(() => startrequest("www.x2.com"));
            Task task3 = Task.Run(() => startrequest("www.x3.com"));
            Task task4 = Task.Run(() => startrequest("www.x4.com"));
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);
```

if I run the method startrequest manually without the use of the Task.Run I always end up by getting the correct data. I am running my PC on I5.

Comment: When you use Task.Run you pull a thread out of the thread pool. Web requests are naturally asynchronous so you should not do it that way. Use HttpClient and async/await - you won't need to pull any additional threads. As for why some are dropping, it is probably the ServicePointManager. I believe on a non-server OS the default connection limit is 10. They will queue up but you can lose some of them if you don't increase that limit.

Comment: So you suggesting that I should increase the limit of the connections made which I believe is limited to 20. however the problem will still remain since that I am not using httpClient and async/await which will work much better with task.run since that it does not require any additional threads but what do you mean by this additional threads anyway following your suggestions will it solve the problem and also the data will be queued up anyway since that the request I make is more than 20 which is the limit

Comment: @ghass `Task.Run` uses dedicated thread from thread pool. `async/await` and mulithreading are different things also

Comment: Task.Run is causing a thread to be consumed from the thread pool. But that is a separate issue from the ServicePointManager connection limit. Just see if it makes a difference if you increase the ServicePointManager connection limit to 100 or so.

Comment: BTW, that is per servicepoint, so if all the URL's are different then that is not the problem.

Comment: Okay I think that worked but The problem is that sometimes I need to make more than 100 request per servicepoint so in that sense I need to refer back to the first solution that you suggested correct of using httpClient and async/await

Comment: As I said, threading is a different issue. It is just more efficient to do I/O bound work asynchronously. You'd still have the same ServicePointManager issue. You can crank the number as high as you want, you don't have to set it at 100.

Comment: Okay would you be able to suggest a solution or an example that conclude all of the points that you have mentioned .

Comment: @crowcoder okay I understand all suggestions that you mentioned but how to fix the problem of task.run droppes out some calls to the method even though I have used the keyword await on all tasks.Run

Comment: @ghass I'm trying to explain that Task.Run is not what is dropping requests. I probably should not have mentioned it because it is just confusing the issue. Unless you are using so many tasks that you starve the thread pool - I'm not sure how many you are starting simulatneously. If that is one of your problems then that issue would go away if you just used an asynchronous API that did not tie up threads.

Comment: I understood now so I need to make the method that makes the requests asynchronous and than I can call as much as I want of the task.run correct. cause I am new to this concept will it work if I make the httpwebrequests to an asynchronous methods rather than using httpclient just for the time being to resolve the issue thanks that will be very useful I guess to resolve my issue thanks. and finally why making an asynchronous   method would resolve the issue yes I am using about 200 task.run at the same time.Also I might end up by using more than 2000 task.run at the same time would that be okay

Comment: @Crowcoder I did all the changes and still I am facing the same problem do I really have to use httpclient or asynchronous httpwebrequest will do the job. I have increased the number of connection to 200 and by the way I have created 20 task.run would be the problem with the threading and if yes what would you suggest

Comment: I would not expect 20 concurrent tasks to be a big problem but try reducing that number until it is stable, then consider batching them in that number.

Comment: A prudent thing to do with http requests is implement a retry policy. Some of your problems could be normal transient errors or throttling by the API you are hitting (I'm only guessing). So you might consider wrapping your requests in [a Polly retry policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

Comment: I have tried all suggestions but nothing works by the way I am still using httpwebrequest would that be the main problem. and I have limited my tasks to two per task and than I do waitAll for each two tasks but nothing helped